# IntelliJ Gitlab revert to older branch locally without affecting remote branches

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitlab

I want to use the IntelliJ windows Gitlab menu interface under Git menu heading to revert to an older branch from the remote repository.  I want to do this locally without affecting the remote branches.  Therefore, when I do this, unless I check something in, the current remote branch should remain in place completely as is.

I currently do not have any local work that needs to be saved.

How do I get the older version, as described above without affecting the remote repository?

Comment: What exactly is your question about this?

Comment: How do I get the older version, as described above without affecting the remote repository?

Comment: And when used the menu interface as you described, did that not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just do this using `git` or the VCS/git IntelliJ features. Just reset your HEAD (`git reset`) to the desired reference point.

Using the IntelliJ VCS utilities, do as follows:

0. Checkout the relevant branch `git checkout my-branch`
1. In the git operations menu, select `Reset HEAD...`
   [image: intellij git menu]
2. In the "Reset Head" dialog, select the Reset type as "hard" and enter the reference you want to revert back to. You can use almost any valid reference (as accepted by `git reset`), like a commit SHA, a relative reference (like `HEAD~10`).
   [image: reset head dialog]

3. Optionally validate the change using the validate button, then click "Reset"

This would be the equivalent of the `git reset` operation:

```sh
REF="abc123"
git reset --hard "$REF"
```

Git reset is a local operation and won't impact anything on the remote unless you push your local changes.